# Python imshow will not overlay -- only display last line's map

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code that when run separately, displays two maps:

Map1:

```
f = h5py.File(filename[0], 'r')
group_id='Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data_AM'
var_id = 'soil_moisture'
a = f[group_id][var_id][:,:]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
a[a==f[group_id][var_id].attrs['_FillValue'].astype(int)]==np.nan;
plt.imshow(a,vmin=0.,vmax=0.55, cmap = 'terrain_r');
cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('$cm^3 cm^{-3}$')
```

[image: Map 1]

Map2:

```
f1 = h5py.File(filename[1], 'r')
b = f1[group_id][var_id][:,:]
b[b==f1[group_id][var_id].attrs['_FillValue'].astype(int)]==np.nan;

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

plt.imshow(b,vmin=0.,vmax=0.55, cmap = 'terrain_r');
cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('$cm^3 cm^{-3}$')
```

[image: Map2]

Trying to overlay the two maps will only display the last line (in this case, *b*):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(a,vmin=0.,vmax=0.55, cmap = 'terrain_r')
plt.imshow(b,vmin=0.,vmax=0.55, cmap = 'terrain_r')
```

What am I possibly missing? Happy to provide more info if needed...

Answer (score 0):

The key would be transparency. You need to make one of the images transparent. That could possibly done by setting an alpha value, see this Stackexchange answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127284/overlay-imshow-plots-in-matplotlib/10127675#10127675 .